# Issues with parsing JSON String to Java

Tags: java, json

I have an issue getting string in an array in an object in JSON array.

my code:

```
JSONArray arraydevice = new JSONArray(devicesJson);

JSONObject objh1 = arraydevice.getJSONObject(0);

System.out.println("The Json object for obj1 is: " + objh1);

JSONObject objh2 = arraydevice.getJSONObject(2);

System.out.println("The Json object for obj2 is: " + objh2);

String host1mac = objh1.getJSONArray("mac").getString(0);

String host2mac = objh2.getJSONArray("mac").getString(0); 

System.out.println("The mac address of the host1 is " + host1mac);

System.out.println("The mac address of the host2 is " + host2mac);
```

The console shows following:

```
The Json object for obj1 is: {"lastSeen":1398513039112,"ipv4":[],"entityClass":"DefaultEntityClass","vlan":[],"mac":["00:00:00:00:00:01"],"attachmentPoint":[{"port":1,"errorStatus":null,"switchDPID":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01"}]}
The Json object for obj2 is: {"lastSeen":1398513039417,"ipv4":[],"entityClass":"DefaultEntityClass","vlan":[],"mac":["00:00:00:00:00:02"],"attachmentPoint":[{"port":1,"errorStatus":null,"switchDPID":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02"}]}
The mac address of the host1 is 00:00:00:00:00:01
Apr 26, 2014 3:26:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [PrintInfo] in context with path [/printinfo_rest] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at core.PrintInfo.doGet(PrintInfo.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

As shown in the console, the server gets and prints the mac address (host1mac) for the first object, but doesn't do it for the other object (host2mac). What's the issue here ?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please show full json

Comment: Check your "array" pointers for null.

Comment: And figure out how to extract the entire exception traceback.

Comment: show complete stacktrace.

Comment: It just doesn't make sense to me, why it works for the first JSON object and doesn't work for the second.

Comment: I'm guessing that the error occurred after the last println, but the buffer wasn't flushed.

Answer (score 0):

A mac address is most likely unique, it would be more appropriate to make it a json object instead of an array.If you cannot change that, here is how you would iterate to get the mac address

```
JSONArray arraydevice = new JSONArray(devicesJson);

for(int i = 0 ; i < arraydevice.length(); i++){
    String hostMac = arraydevice.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getJSONArray("mac")
                                .getString(0);
    System.out.println("The mac address of the host" + i + "is: " + hostMac);
}
```